# Powers of \dl with diffcoeff

Tags: errors, diffcoeff

In version 4, I used to be able to write the equivalent of `\mathrm{d}^4 x` as `\dl^4 x`. However in version 5 I get and error about a "Missing { inserted". Is there a way to fix the problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\dl^4 x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work anymore" mean? You get an error? Unexpected output? Also, if you give a complete minimal example, nobody else has to type the extra other stuff in...

Comment: @mickep Thanks, I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v5 of `diffcoeff` the differential as a whole can be raised to a power, but to raise the operator symbol, the `d`, to a power you need to use the `\difc` (`c' for compact-form derivative) command. Thus `\difc[4]x{{}}` gives what you want, but I imagine uses more keystrokes than desired. To reduce the keystrokes, call a new macro (say) `\dfl` and write

```
\NewDocumentCommand \dfl { E{^}{1} m } { \difc[#1]{#2}{{}} }
```

Then `\dfl^4 x` will give what you want (and `\dfl x` will give dx).

Comment: That's great, thank you! The only aspect missing is that the new `\dfl` doesn't inherit the horizontal space on the left from `\dfl`. What's the equivalent of, say, `\difdef { l } {} { outer-Ldelim = \onemu }`?

Comment: The simplest is to precede the ```\difc``` with the desired space in the definition of ```\dfl```:

Comment: Alternatively, define a variant of ```\difc``` like ```\difdef { c } { dfl } { outer-Ldelim=\onemu, outer-Rdelim=\nilmu}``` and change the definition of ```\dfl``` slightly: ```\NewDocumentCommand \dfl { E{^}{1} m } { \difc[#1]{#2}{{}} []``` where I've added empty square brackets at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old version as `[=v4]` I couldn't see if there is a supported syntax in the new version

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}[=v4]

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\dl^4 x 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I indeed noticed that this was the case.

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use a completely different command, `\difc`, just to typeset this? And this package uses *dots* of all things as argument delimiters (yes, I know many people feel the same way about `g`-type arguments, but I respectfully disagree)? This is a classical example of why I prefer keyval syntax, such as the following (I used my own package to make this, but this should be taken as an encouragement to the authors of `diffcoeff`, `derivative`, and other packages to embrace keyval syntax):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\DifferentialOperator[
    bool provide=in pars,
    define keys={
        {in pars}{
            use par=false,
            bool set true=in pars,
            set arg dots={\dotsc},
            set arg sep={,},
        },
        {not in pars}{
            use par=never,
            bool set false=in pars,
            set arg dots={\dotsm},
            set arg sep={\,},
        },
    },
    not in pars,
    define keys[1]={
        {pow}{upper={#1}},
    },
    prepend keys[1]={
        {arg}{
            bool if TF={in pars}
            {
                define arg keys[1]={
                    {default}{
                        sep={####1},
                    }
                },
            }{
                return,
                define arg keys[1]={
                    {default}{
                        set arg keys x={
                            other sep={%
                                \SemantexDataGetExpNot{arg sep}%
                                \SemantexDataGetExpNot{symbol}%
                            }{%
                                \SemantexExpNot{####1}%
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    },
]

\NewObject\DifferentialOperator\dl{d}
\NewObject\DifferentialOperator\dlpartial{\partial}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \dl
    =
    \dl{x}
    =
    \dl[pow=4]
    =
    \dl{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[pow=4]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u,pow=4]{x,y,...,z}
\\
    \dlpartial
    =
    \dlpartial{x}
    =
    \dlpartial[pow=4]
    =
    \dlpartial{x,y,z}
    =
    \dlpartial[pow=4]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dlpartial[u]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dlpartial[u,pow=4]{x,y,...,z}
\\
    \dl[in pars]
    =
    \dl[in pars]{x}
    =
    \dl[in pars,pow=4]
    =
    \dl[in pars]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[in pars,pow=4]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u,in pars]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u,in pars,pow=4]{x,y,...,z}
\\
    \SetupObject\dl{in pars}
    \dl
    =
    \dl{x}
    =
    \dl[pow=4]
    =
    \dl{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[pow=4]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u]{x,y,z}
    =
    \dl[u,pow=4]{x,y,...,z}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The derivative package already uses a keyval syntax :)

Comment: @Simon Only for setting it up, not this way. 